# how to iterate through consecutive lines of a csv file

Tags: python-2.7, csv, iterator

Sorry for the rookie question. I'm trying to iterate through consecutive (tuples) lines of a csv file in python. what I'm trying is this:

```
with open ('my_file.csv','rb') as f_obj:
    reader=csv.reader(f_obj)
    for f_row , s_row in zip(reader , reader[1:]):
          do something
```

it does not work with izip as well. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `csv.reader` in an iterator, and as such it can only be read once, then it's exhausted. Also, an iterator is not indexable, so `zip(reader , reader[1:])` does not work.

I suggest you use [`itertools.tee`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) to copy the reader, skip one line on one of the readers, and then `zip` those:

```
with open('my_file.csv') as f_obj:
    reader1, reader2 = itertools.tee(csv.reader(f_obj))
    next(reader2) # skip first line in reader2
    for f_row , s_row in zip(reader1, reader2):
          print f_row, s_row
```

For input file containing numbers `1` through `5` on separate lines, output is

```
['1'] ['2']
['2'] ['3']
['3'] ['4']
['4'] ['5']
```